# Как ресайзить JTextArea по размеру текста

Tags: java, swing

Либо как можно сделать многострочный текст в JTextArea по центру?

Answer (score 1):

`JTextArea` не поддерживает выравнивание текста, а для ресайза нужны костыли - стандартного решения нет. Можно попробовать вместо текстовой области использовать текстовый редактор `JTextPane`, там можно редактировать набор атрибутов текста, и выравнивание в том числе:

```
StyledDocument doc = me.getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet centerAlignment = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(centerAlignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), centerAlignment, false);
```

Comment: Уже, конечно, давно не актуально, но если пригодится, проверю

Comment: @Herrgott Ну, поздно - лучше чем никогда=)